# Is there a simple safe way to read a Groovy map from an external file?

Tags: groovy

I want to store a config as a map in a separate file

Does Groovy have a builtin way of doing this? I don't want to store the config as a json file and have to read and convert it- I want to store it in a separate file as regular Groovy code.

For example I'll have a file in the same dir like this:

```
// in file myconfig.groovy
def myconfig = [
        [
                "confignode1"              : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf",
                "param1"                   : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj",
                "param2"                   : "sdkjlskjdflskf"
        ],
        [
                "confignode2"              : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf",
                "param1"                   : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj",
                "param2"                   : "sdkjlskjdflskf"
        ]
]
```

Is there a way Groovy can import that file and I can just access myconfig like a regular map?

Comment: Check ConfigSlurper or GroovyShell classes

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a JSON: List->JSON->File and load the same way but vise versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `evaluate` if you change myconfig.groovy to return Map like this:

```
// in file myconfig.groovy
[
        [
                "confignode1": "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf",
                "param1"     : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj",
                "param2"     : "sdkjlskjdflskf"
        ],
        [
                "confignode2": "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf",
                "param1"     : "lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj",
                "param2"     : "sdkjlskjdflskf"
        ]
]
```

It can be used this way:

```
// in file main.groovy
def myconfig = evaluate(new File("myconfig.groovy"))
println myconfig
```

Result:

```
> groovy main.groovy
[[confignode1:lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf, param1:lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj, param2:sdkjlskjdflskf], [confignode2:lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkjf, param1:lsdkfjlskdfjlsdkj, param2:sdkjlskjdflskf]]
```